# Spring Cloud Stream - query topic without consuming a KTable/KStream explicitly?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream library in a Java application. I want to use the Kafka Streams binder for a state store. The application will post messages to a topic, and I wish to use the Kafka Streams `InteractiveQueryService` to retrieve data from the same topic. Is it possible to perform such queries as-is, or do I need to first consume the topic as a KTable/KStream and materialize it before I can perform queries? I don't have any requirement to perform KTable/KStream processing on the topic, I just want to query the topic contents. I'm hoping there is some way to implicitly materialize it as a state store.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive Queries is a feature that allows you to query client side state states. It's not a feature that allows you to query topics.

Hence, if you have data in a topic that you want to query it using "Interactive Queries", you need to load the data into a state store within Kafka Streams.